# How to get title using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax functionality and trying to get title using ajax but not working. Here is a example

```js
$('#ajaxlink').click(function(e) {
  var $this = this.href;
  $.ajax({
    url: $this,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
      var div = $('title', $(html));
      $('#gettitle').text($title);
      
     console.log(html);
     }

  });


  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="ajaxlink" href="https://jsfiddle.net/">Click</a>
<div id="gettitle">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is failing because of CORS protection. You can't easily request html from other domains and parse the results, unless they have enabled CORS explicitly.

To make it work for same domain, try this

```
$('#gettitle').text($(html).filter('title').text());
```

Comment: How can i get this from same domain?? but not same page title. i'm using full ajax page change option but want to change title when page change using `pushstate`. Everythig working fine but i can't get the title using this example.

Comment: Try this ? $('#gettitle').text($(html).filter('title').text());

Comment: 1 more question and i accept your answer that does .filter support all brwser??

Comment: Yes it does @Debar

Comment: Thanks 4 help bro. :)

Answer (score 0):

I saw some problems in your code, 
Please try this version of your code

```js
$('#ajaxlink').click(function(e) {
  var urlPath =  $(e.currentTarget).prop('href'); // must be a valid url
  $.ajax({
    url: urlPath,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
      $('#gettitle').text(html);
     console.log(html);
     }

  });


  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="ajaxlink" href="https://jsfiddle.net/">Click</a>
<div id="gettitle">
</div>
```

Comment: @Debar What kind of error are raised in the console ?

Comment: I'm using full ajax page change option but want to change title when page change using `pushstate`. Everythig working fine but i can't get the title using this example.

Comment: I also tried `$(html).find('title').text()` or `$(html).filter('title')` but not worked.

Comment: @Debar please se MoustafaS answer. the main problem is CORS protection

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONP:

```
function logResults(json){
  console.log(json);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.github.com/users/jeresig",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "logResults"
});

});
```

or

```
function jsonCallback(json){
  console.log(json);
}

$(document).ready(function(){



$.ajax({
  url: "http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/v8xyYN64V4nqCshgjKms/data-2.json",
  dataType: "jsonp"
});

});
```

Comment: Does it support all browser?

Comment: Is jQuery a crossbrowser framework? ...yes. With jsonp you don't have to enable CORS. Downside is exceptionhandling.